# How to replace a yield with a map in Scala?

Tags: scala, yield

how can I remove this yield's? I wanna use a map instead of:

```
val cols = for(x <- 0 to 6) yield for(y <- 0 to 5) yield apply(x, y)
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Best regards,
John

Comment: In general: `for (x <- seq) yield f(x)` is translated as `seq.map(x => f(x))`

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but just in case: `val cols = Vector.tabulate(7,6)(apply)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That would be pretty simple:

```
val cols = (0 to 6).map(x => (0 to 5).map( y => apply(x,y)))
```

### UPD

There may be variations in `map`s. If you want flat object without nested structure it is better to use `flatMap` instead of just `map`:

```
def apply(x: Int, y: Int) = (x,y)
scala> val cols = (0 to 6).map(x => (0 to 5).map( y => apply(x,y)))
//cols: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Int)]] =  ...

scala> val cols = (0 to 6).flatMap(x => (0 to 5).map( y => apply(x,y)))
//cols: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Int)] = ...
```

or just flatten result at the end:

```
scala> val cols = (0 to 6).map(x => (0 to 5).map( y => apply(x,y))).flatten
//cols: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Int)] = ...
```

Comment: I have got one more question. When I use this code and I print this cols println("cols: "+cols) I get 2 lines. Why?

Comment: @user1137701 can you, please, specify your desired output, and what you got? I suspect that's cause I've used `map` which saves inner structure, instead of `flatMap` which returns unnested object

Comment: Hey, yes I have got this:
`code`
val array = Array.fill(7)(Array.fill(6)(None:Option[Coin]))

def apply(x: Int, y: Int):Option[Coin] = 
     if (0 <= x && x < 7 && 0 <= y && y < 6) array(x)(y)
     else None

val cols = (0 until 7).map(x => (0 until 6).map( y => apply(x,y)))
`code`
When I print the cols, I get them twice...

Answer (score 6):

When you have more than one generators, the innermost one translates to `map`, and rest translate to `flatMap`. (In your case, those aren't nested generators.)

The following examples may help:

```
scala> val xs, ys, zs = Vector(1, 4, 5)
xs: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 4, 5)
ys: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 4, 5)
zs: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 4, 5)

scala> for {
     |   x <- xs
     |   y <- ys
     |   z <- zs
     | } yield (x, y, z)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[(Int, Int, Int)] = Vector((1,1,1), (1,1,4), (1,1,5), (1,4,1), (1,4,4), (1,4,5), (1,5,1), (1,5,4), (1,5,5), (4,1,1), (4,1,4), (4,1,5), (4,4,1), (4,4,4), (4,4,5), (4,5,1), (4,5,4), (4,5,5), (5,1,1), (5,1,4), (5,1,5), (5,4,1), (5,4,4), (5,4,5), (5,5,1), (5,5,4), (5,5,5))

scala> xs flatMap { x =>
     |   ys flatMap { y =>
     |     zs map { z =>
     |       (x, y, z)
     |     }
     |   }
     | }
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[(Int, Int, Int)] = Vector((1,1,1), (1,1,4), (1,1,5), (1,4,1), (1,4,4), (1,4,5), (1,5,1), (1,5,4), (1,5,5), (4,1,1), (4,1,4), (4,1,5), (4,4,1), (4,4,4), (4,4,5), (4,5,1), (4,5,4), (4,5,5), (5,1,1), (5,1,4), (5,1,5), (5,4,1), (5,4,4), (5,4,5), (5,5,1), (5,5,4), (5,5,5))

scala> res0 == res1
res2: Boolean = true

scala> for {
     |   x <- xs
     |   y <- ys
     | } yield for {
     |   z <- zs
     | } yield (x, y, z)
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[(Int, Int, Int)]] = Vector(Vector((1,1,1), (1,1,4), (1,1,5)), Vector((1,4,1), (1,4,4), (1,4,5)), Vector((1,5,1), (1,5,4), (1,5,5)), Vector((4,1,1), (4,1,4), (4,1,5)), Vector((4,4,1), (4,4,4), (4,4,5)), Vector((4,5,1), (4,5,4), (4,5,5)), Vector((5,1,1), (5,1,4), (5,1,5)), Vector((5,4,1), (5,4,4), (5,4,5)), Vector((5,5,1), (5,5,4), (5,5,5)))

scala> xs flatMap { x =>
     |   ys map { y =>
     |     zs map { z =>
     |       (x, y, z)
     |     }
     |   }
     | }
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[(Int, Int, Int)]] = Vector(Vector((1,1,1), (1,1,4), (1,1,5)), Vector((1,4,1), (1,4,4), (1,4,5)), Vector((1,5,1), (1,5,4), (1,5,5)), Vector((4,1,1), (4,1,4), (4,1,5)), Vector((4,4,1), (4,4,4), (4,4,5)), Vector((4,5,1), (4,5,4), (4,5,5)), Vector((5,1,1), (5,1,4), (5,1,5)), Vector((5,4,1), (5,4,4), (5,4,5)), Vector((5,5,1), (5,5,4), (5,5,5)))

scala> res3 == res4
res5: Boolean = true

scala> for {
     |   x <- xs
     | } yield for {
     |   y <- ys
     |   z <- zs
     | } yield (x, y, z)
res6: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[(Int, Int, Int)]] = Vector(Vector((1,1,1), (1,1,4), (1,1,5), (1,4,1), (1,4,4), (1,4,5), (1,5,1), (1,5,4), (1,5,5)), Vector((4,1,1), (4,1,4), (4,1,5), (4,4,1), (4,4,4), (4,4,5), (4,5,1), (4,5,4), (4,5,5)), Vector((5,1,1), (5,1,4), (5,1,5), (5,4,1), (5,4,4), (5,4,5), (5,5,1), (5,5,4), (5,5,5)))

scala> xs map { x =>
     |   ys flatMap { y =>
     |     zs map { z =>
     |       (x, y, z)
     |     }
     |   }
     | }
res7: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[(Int, Int, Int)]] = Vector(Vector((1,1,1), (1,1,4), (1,1,5), (1,4,1), (1,4,4), (1,4,5), (1,5,1), (1,5,4), (1,5,5)), Vector((4,1,1), (4,1,4), (4,1,5), (4,4,1), (4,4,4), (4,4,5), (4,5,1), (4,5,4), (4,5,5)), Vector((5,1,1), (5,1,4), (5,1,5), (5,4,1), (5,4,4), (5,4,5), (5,5,1), (5,5,4), (5,5,5)))

scala> res6 == res7
res8: Boolean = true
```